# Antlr getting mismatched input '(' expecting '(' exception

Tags: antlr

I am trying to write Antlr Grammer for the below statement:

```
data (DROP=hello);
```

My Antlr Grammer is:

```
DATA '(' DROP EQUAL 'hello' ')' ';'
```

Not sure what is it i am missing here.  My test statement is:

```
Data File1(compress=char REUSE=YES);
```

1. Main Grammar file:

   grammar ParseSAS;
   import CommonGrammar,DataStmt;

   ```
      /*NOTE: When i execute my grammar on data_stmt it works fine but on Parse level it fails*/

       parse
        : (data_stmt
         )*EOF
       ; 
       /*** End of Parse Grammar
   ```

The below DataStmt Grammar is to parse datastatement directly

2. DataStatement Grammer file:

   ```
       grammar DataStmt;
       import CommonGrammar;

       parse
        : (data_stmt)* EOF
        ;

       data_stmt
        : DATA ';'
        | DATA Tk_NULL datastmt_cmd? NOLIST? ';' 
        | DATA dataset_name_opt+ datastmt_cmd? NOLIST? ';'
        | DATA view_dsname_opt+ '/' VIEW '=' view_name passwd_opt? source_opt? NESTING? NOLIST? ';'
        | DATA dataset_name '/' PGM '=' program_name passwd_opt? source_opt? NESTING? NOLIST? ';'
        | DATA VIEW '=' view_name passwd_opt? NOLIST? ';'
        | DATA PGM '=' program_name passwd_opt? NOLIST? ';'
        ;

       dataset_name_opt
        : dataset_name ('(' variables '=' (~('('|')'))*? ')')?
        ;

       datastmt_cmd
        : '/' DEBUG? NESTING? (STACK '=' INT)?
        ;

        // view-name <data-set-name-1 <(data-set-options-1)>>
       view_dsname_opt
        : variables variables? ('(' variables '=' (~('('|')'))*? ')')?
        ;

       view_name : variables  ;
       dataset_name : variables;
       program_name : variables;
       passwd_opt  : '(' (ALTER|READ|PW) '=' (~('('|')'))*? ')' ;
       source_opt : ('(' SOURCE '=' (SAVE | ENCRYPT | NOSAVE) ')') ;
   ```
3. Common Grammar file with all the common functionality:

   ```
       CommonGrammar.g4:

       grammar CommonGrammar;

       expression
        : literal
        | Identifier
        | DOT
        | OUTPUT Identifier?
        | '(' expression ')'
        | expression '(' expressionList? ')'
        | expression '{' expression '}'
        | expression '[' expression ']'
        | NOT expression
        | expression MIN expression
        | expression MAX expression
        | expression ('*'|'/'|'%') expression
        | expression ('+'|'-') expression
        | expression ('||' | '!!' ) expression
        | expression (EQ | NE | GT | LT | GE | LE | EQUAL ) expression
        | expression (EQC | NEC | GTC | LTC | GEC | LEC ) expression
        | expression (IN | INColon| NOT IN) in_var_list
        | expression (AND | OR ) expression
        | LIST
        ;
       expressionList 
        : (expression | of_var_list) (',' (expression|of_var_list))*
        | expressionList ','+ expressionList
        ;

       of_var_list 
        : 'of' (Identifier '-' Identifier) ((COMMA 'of')? (Identifier '-' Identifier) )*
        | 'of' Identifier Identifier*
        | 'of' Identifier '[' '*' ']'
        ;
       identifiers_list
        : (Identifier | Identifier '-' Identifier |Identifier ',' Identifier ','Identifier)+
        ;

       in_var_list
        : Identifier
        | '(' (literal|colonInts) (',' (literal|colonInts))* ')'
        ;
       colonInts
        : INT ':' INT
        ;

       literal
        : INT
        | FloatingPointLiteral
        | STRINGLITERAL
        | DateLiteral
        | TimeLiteral
        | DateTimeLiteral
        | BitLiteral
        | NameLiteral
        | HexLiteral
        | DOT
        ;

       variables
        : variables DOT variables
        | Identifier
        // place all the keywords here to resolve "keywords can also be identifiers" problem   
        ;
       /**
        * Tokens 
        * */

       // Drop
       DROP: D R O P;
       DATA: D A T A;

       Identifier  : [a-zA-Z_] ([a-zA-Z_0-9])*  ;
   ```

When i execute the grammar on DataStatement level it works file but when i execute it on Parse Level it says:

> ParseSAS::parse:1:10: no viable alternative at input 'Data File1('

Comment: Please show your entire grammar.

Comment: Would be happy to take a look at it, with the full grammar and your test input and expected result.

Comment: I just created all three grammar files and ran ANTLR4 Tool on ParseSAS, got a huge screen full of errors. Lots of "cannot create implicit token for string literal" errors.  Something isn't right, I cannot reproduce your error from this.

Comment: IS there anyway i can attach my source files here instead of copy pasting the contents?

Comment: Hang on. Which is it? `data (DROP=hello);` or `Data File1(compress=char REUSE=YES);`?

Comment: Data File1(compress=char REUSE=YES);

Answer (score 0):

This error usually comes up when you have both a lexer rule which matches this input and also use a string literal for the same input in a parser rule. Don't do that. Always define your lexer input in lexer rules and don't use string literals in parser rules.

**Update**: After you uploaded your grammars I see you almost have no lexer rules for your literals. You certainly should restructure your grammars and move all literals into a common lexer grammar.